# php/regex: How to replace part of a found pattern, but leaving the rest as it is?

Tags: php, regex

How can I replace a substring in a found pattern, but leaving the rest as it is?

(EDIT: The real case is of course more complicated than the example below, I have to match occurrences within xml tags. That's why I have to use regex!)

Let's say I want to change occurrences of the letter "X" within a word to the letter "Z".

I want

> aaXaa aaX Xaa

to become

> aaZaa aaZ Zaa

Finding occurrences of words including "x" isn't a problem, like this:

> [^X\s]*X[^\s]*

but a normal preg_match replaces the complete match, where I want anything in the pattern except "X" to stay as it is.

Which is the best way to accomplish this in php?

Comment: Your regex would not match the X at the end of the second word.

Comment: I'm confused, doesn't a simple replace do exactly what you ask? Replacing the matching pattern and leaving the rest as is.

Comment: Sorry for cunfusing. I have to user regex, my example was a bit over-simplified!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If your regex matches only the relevant part, it should be no problem that it replaces the complete match (like `preg_replace('/X/', 'Z', $string)`).

But if you need the regex to contain parts that should not be replaced, you need to capture them and insert them back:

```
preg_replace('/(non-replace)X(restofregex)/', '$1Z$2', $string);
```

Comment: Thank you, Soulmerge! Exactly what I needed!

Comment: I found when concatenating a string variable between the two matching groups I had to put the numbers in curly brackets, like this `'${1}' . $foo . '${2}'`, otherwise it didn't work. Why is that?

Comment: If instead of `Z` you need to put value from a variable that you do not control, then you need to escape the `$` and `\number` characters, and this is quite a difficult task. Use `preg_replace_callback`, an example is in my answer to the question.

Answer (score 3):

If it's really as simple as replacing `X` with `Z`, you can also use `str_replace()`, which is faster than using `preg` in this case:

```
$sNew = str_replace("X", "Z", $sOld);
```

Comment: I get your point, and the real case is of course more complicated. I will use it for handling namespace tags in xml-documents, so there has to be real regex for this!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?php
$string = 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.';
$patterns[0] = '/quick/';
$patterns[1] = '/brown/';
$patterns[2] = '/fox/';
$replacements[2] = 'bear';
$replacements[1] = 'black';
$replacements[0] = 'slow';
echo preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $string);
?>
```

The above example will output:

```
The bear black slow jumped over the lazy dog.
```

Comment: You need to ksort the arrays before you call preg_replace, so that the right patterns get substituted by the right values: ksort($patterns);
ksort($replacements);

Answer (score 0):

Do you really have to use regex for this?

```
$output = str_replace('X', 'Z', $input);
```

Answer (score 0):

For difficult regular expressions where you need to replace part of a string, it can be very useful to do so (and most importantly, **you don't need to escape `$newValue` for the characters `$` and `\number`**):

```
$newValue = 'NewValue';

$newString = preg_replace_callback(
  '/(<Element>).*(<\/Element>)/',
  function($match) use ($newValue) { return $match[1].$newValue.$match[2]; },
  $string
);
```

---

Unreliable usage:

In `preg_replace('/(<Element>).*(<\/Element>)/', '$1NewValue$2', $string)`: if instead of `NewValue` you need to put value from a variable that you do not control, then **you need to escape the `$` and `\number` characters**, and this is quite a difficult task.